# SSRS 2015 hangs after two parameter changes

Tags: reporting-services

My question is about the following scenario:
In SSRS 2015 one report keeps refusing to render(hangs on a blank report) under specific circumstances.
Here is the scenario.

1. Open the report, which automatically renders (Functions perfectly)
2. Alter one parameter (it doesn't matter which one), render the report (Functions perfectly)
3. Alter a another parameter (It could be the same one or a different one), render the report. **It hangs.** There is no actual error shown, but the report just hangs with nothing displayed.

Specifically; The parameters are all greyed out and no report is rendered. The "View report" button is still visible and appears active, but nothing happens when you click on it.

The only way to make the report function again is to back completely out of it and re-enter the report from the beginning.

It is important to note that none of the sub-reports are effected. You can drill through to them as much as you like and nothing will hang.
Also, this functions perfectly on our 2012 server and that no other reports on either server have encountered this error.
I can't even replicate it in Visual Studio.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your issue when **Deployed** to Report Manager/Reporting Services Web Portal? I have had issues after deploying a report that has parameter changes. I usually end up deleting the report from the report server and redeploying.

Comment: Yes. When previewing in VS everything works fine.
We tried deleting and redeploying the project, but nothing changed.
The current theory on our side is that the server couldn't handle the demand or that some configuration needs to be tweaked. When we pointed the intranet link back to the 2012 server the demand on the 2015 server went way down and the problem stopped occurring. 
No error or warning was thrown on the system resource side. That makes it hard to be sure resources are the problem.